# Check if scroll is triggered or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mousewheel

I am building a website and in this website I have an event on my mousewheel. The problem is that when you scroll your mouse on a mac (with a magic mouse) the scroll event is called so many times that at one moment the scroll function will totally freak out and isn't smooth anymore.

Does anyone know how you can tackle this problem?
I already tried to check the `e.orginalEvent` but it always returns `DOMMouseWheel`.
Also on a PC you don't have this problem and with an other mouse then the magic mouse it works great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need the debounce/throttle plugin here http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ .

It allows you set up events to fire only after a certain period like 1 second. This way your page Isn't flooded with mousewheel events or if someone thinks clicking the submit button of a form a MILLION times will make it submit faster...

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)'s [`throttle`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle) function.

From the documentation:

> Returns a throttled version of the function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the wrapped function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.